# Do conduction electrons recombine with positive donor atoms?

Tags: analog, semiconductors

Once the 5th valence electron of a donor atom left, it will be to the conduction band, so the donor atom becomes positively charged.
My question is if it is possible, that a free electron from the conduction band recombines with the  positively charged donor ion. So is regeneration possible because of the donor ion?

Comment: Yes, it's called recombination.  In a semiconductor at room temperature we assume that all or nearly all of the dopant atoms are contributing charge carriers but there's nothing preventing them from accepting an electron or hole.  They will probably lose it quickly thereafter though.

Comment: Sure: electron-hole recombination is common, and can be helpful in an LED, or detrimental in a transistor. See https://eng.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Materials_Science/Supplemental_Modules_(Materials_Science)/Electronic_Properties/Electron-Hole_Recombination

Answer (score 2):

Recombination takes place when electron falls from conduction band to valence band, thus one free electron and one free hole disappear.

Jumping of electron from donor dopant atom onto conduction band is called donor ionization, and reverse process is called electron capture. In these cases holes concentration does not change.